# http://code.google.com/p/fontidguide/wiki/Changelog

Tags: fonts, texlive

According to the change log at

http://code.google.com/p/fontidguide/wiki/Changelog

the "Edwardian Script ITC" font should be available in TexLive version 20110727. However, it doesn't appear to be.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Regards,
Jeff.

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use a newer version of TeX Live? 2011 is pretty old.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5):

That is not a list of fonts included in TeX Live. It is a list of fonts covered by an identification guide but most of the fonts are not and will not be in TeX Live.

The reference to TeX Live is just a note concerning the version used to produce the guide. That is, it is saying that because they updated to TeX Live 2011, the guide itself is 30% smaller. TeX Live is just the software used to produce the guide. The contents of the guide has nothing to do with TeX.